# Adobe AIR Android launching in landscape doesn't work

Tags: android, flash, air, adobe

The app i am developing should be displayed only in landscape mode.

In my app descriptor i have

```
    <aspectRatio>landscape</aspectRatio>
    <autoOrients>false</autoOrients>
```

On iOS devices app is launched in landscape mode and everything works as expected.

But when i tried to deploy on my android device ( Samsung galaxy S3 ), the app is launched in portrait mode.

When I modify the descriptor file to read :

```
    <aspectRatio>landscape</aspectRatio>
    <autoOrients>true</autoOrients>
```

then the app will be changing orientation.

While debugging i found out that the apps orientation when starting is stage.orientation == "default"

Also i have added `android:screenOrientation="landscape"` to android specific configurations in my app.xml (the app descriptor file):

```
<android>
    <manifestAdditions>
        <![CDATA[
        <manifest android:installLocation="auto">
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>

            <uses-feature android:required="true" android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch"/>
            <application android:enabled="true">
                <activity android:excludeFromRecents="false" android:screenOrientation="landscape">
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                    </intent-filter>
                </activity>
            </application>
        </manifest>
        ]]>
        </manifestAdditions>

     <!--Color depth for the app (either "32bit" or "16bit"). Optional. Default 16bit before namespace 3.0, 32bit after -->
    <!--<colorDepth></colorDepth>-->
</android>
```

Is this a known issue? What could be the cause of this?

EDIT:

I ended up using `stage.setAspectRatio( StageAspectRatio.LANDSCAPE );` in my main class. It will work even with devices that have default orientation other than PORTRAIT

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problems with orientation. As i needed to restrict orientation change only for certain devices i solved it by setting values at runtime (before app has fully initialised).

In main application tag, listen for preinitialize event:

```
<s:Application ...
    preinitialize="preinit()">
```

And set orientation values in listener:

```
private function preinit():void
{
    systemManager.stage.setOrientation(StageOrientation.ROTATED_LEFT);
    systemManager.stage.autoOrients = false;
}
```

Or try StageOrientation.ROTATED_RIGHT instead.

Edit: As Josh commented, this will only work for devices with portrait as the default (ie: your Samsung S3).

Comment: You can't rely on the `StageOrientation` constants to determine if it is landscape or not. They rely on the default orientation, which may not always be what you expect it to be (some wider tablets use landscape as default, while most use portrait). You need to rotate and verify the `stage.stageWidth` is greater (in landscape)/less (in portrait) than `stage.stageHeight` to be sure you are in the correct orientation.

Comment: Agreed, but phone default is always portrait so rotated orientations are always landscape. I've edited my answer to clarify.

Comment: You're right that you can generally assume, but you shouldn't rely on it as it takes some control out of your hands and puts it in the manufacturers or (worse) Adobe's. AIR itself has been known to report wrong default orientations in the past despite the device itself being correct (the first retina iPad had this issue for sure and I think the first retina iPhone may have as well)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I ended up using the `stage.setAspectRatio( StageAspectRatio.LANDSCAPE );` which i think is the most correct way and will also work with devices with default value other than PORTRAIT